# Convert JavaScript collection declaration code to corresponding C# code

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm developing Windows Phone app which consuming web API calls. Most of call are returning JSON strings, but one of them return the following line of code:

```
var buyPrice=[[Date.UTC(2012,0,9),385.250000], [Date.UTC(2012,0,10),386.250000], [Date.UTC(2012,0,11),387.000000]];
```

It seems that above mentioned line of code is a regular declaration of JavaScript collection. It does mean I can't parse it as JSON, moreover it contains a word

> "var buyPrice="

which can't be parsed as well.

So I need to convert above mentioned collection to the corresponding C# array/collection, but not sure I'm able to do that.

Is it possible to do this by using C# abilities or I need some third party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without external librairies (and I don't know any for this kind of tasks), you can use `Regex`:

```
var input = "var buyPrice=[[Date.UTC(2012,0,9),385.250000], [Date.UTC(2012,0,10),386.250000], [Date.UTC(2012,0,11),387.000000]];"

var regex = @"\[Date.UTC\((?<year>\d{4}),(?<month>\d{1,2}),(?<day>\d{1,2})\),(?<price>\d+(\.\d+)?)]";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, regex)
                   .OfType<Match>()
                   .Select(m => new
                       {
                           Date = new DateTime(
                               Int32.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value),
                               Int32.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value) + 1,
                               Int32.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value)
                           ),
                           Price = Decimal.Parse(m.Groups["price"].Value)
                       });
```

Because [Date.UTC takes a month starting from 0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FUTC), you have to add one. Based on your input, this will return three anonymous object with a `Datetime Date` and `decimal Price` properties.

Note that this Regex does not try to validate the input (the month and day 00-99 is valid), but it's a good starting point.

Comment: Just awesome! Thanks. I think this is a best way to parse my data. If it is interesting for you I found some libraries which are fully meets my requirements. Here are some best libraries: Jint (http://jint.codeplex.com/), Jurassic (http://jurassic.codeplex.com/), JavaScript.NET (http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/). Although they are all cool libraries I will use the method from the answer.